# Pyhook: using KeyboardEvents and MouseEvents together

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyhook

I'm making a screenshot utility for personal use and I want to add in bounding box screenshots. I want to be able to press insert on the 2 corners of the area and then grab the screenshot.

The issue is that I can't get the keyboard and mouse events to work with each other. I can't seem to get the mouse position.

This is what I have so far:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time
import pythoncom, pyHook

mospos = None

def OnMouseEvent(event):
    print 'MessageName:',event.MessageName
    print 'Message:',event.Message
    print 'Position:',event.Position
    print '---'
    mospos = event.Position
    return True

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print 'KeyID:', event.KeyID#Show KeyID of keypress
    if(event.KeyID == 44):#Prntscr
        print 'Print Screen'
        im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
        im.save('img'+time.strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S")+'.png','PNG')#save with Day-Month-Year_Hour-Minute_Second format
    if(event.KeyID == 45):#insert
        print mospos

    return True# return True to pass the event to other handlers


hm = pyHook.HookManager()# create a hook manager
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent# watch for all key events
hm.MouseAll = OnMouseEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()# set the hook
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()# wait forever
```

mospos never changes from 'None' even after I cause mouse events.

How do I get the mouse position from the keyboard event handler?

p.s. I'm eternally sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that mospos is not used as a global variable in your code.

In `OnMouseEvent`, when you set mospos to `event.position`, you just set a local variable, incidentally named mospos. **It is not the same variable!**

You have to explicitly declare that in `OnMouseEvent`, mospos is to be treated as a global variable, using the `global` keyword.

```
def OnMouseEvent(event):
    global mospos
    mospos = event.Position
    return True
```

That way, you will be able to read the current mouse position in `OnKeyboardEvent`.

Here is what your OnKeyboardEvent callback may look like, with yet another global variable used to store one corner of the area (grab screen on second insert press):

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global origin
    if(event.KeyID == 45):  # insert
        if origin is None:
            origin = mospos
        else:
            bbox = (min(origin[0], mospos[0]), 
                    min(origin[1], mospos[1]), 
                    max(origin[0], mospos[0]), 
                    max(origin[1], mospos[1]))
            im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
            im.save('img'+time.strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S")+'.png','PNG')  # save with Day-Month-Year_Hour-Minute_Second format
            origin = None
    return True
```

Note however that it may be overkill to use a mouseHook just to get the cursor position when you press a given key.

Another solution would be to use call `GetCursorInfo()` from `win32gui` in your keyboard hook.

```
flags, hcursor, mospos = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()
```